# Proof that there exists an integer $n \geqslant2$ such that $n^2$ divides $2^n + 3^n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Proof that there exists an integer $n \geqslant 2$ such that $n^2$ divides $2^n + 3^n$. I came up with this problem and I don't have a clue how to start, or even if it is not trivial at all.

Comment: It is not true. Try with $n = 2$.

Comment: It won't be true for any even number n.

Comment: As @TobiasKildetoft suggested, it is worth trying with simple cases first.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: In the new version, $n = 1$ works

Comment: Say $n \neq 1$.

Comment: @AnTer Put it in the question and make it right for good, if you please.

Comment: It is true for some values, e.g. $\rm\: n = 5\:$ and $\rm\:n =55.\ \ $

Comment: For a similar problem with no definitive answer known, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16341/on-polynomials-dividing-exponentials  which is just: Find all positive integers $m$ such that $m^2 - 1$ divides $3^m + 5^m.$ The only known solution is $m=3.$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2^n+3^n$ is divisible by $n^2$. Then, $2^n+3^n\equiv 0 \bmod n^2$. In particular, $2^n+3^n\equiv 0 \bmod n$. Suppose for convenience that $n=p\neq 2,3$ is a prime number. Then, by Fermat's little theorem, $2^p\equiv 2 \bmod p$ and $3^p\equiv 3 \bmod p$, so
$$2^p+3^p\equiv 2+3\equiv 5 \bmod p.$$
Hence, if $2^p+3^p\equiv 0 \bmod p$, we must have $p=5$. And indeed, $p=5$ works, 
$$2^5+3^5 = 275 = 11\cdot 25.$$
Hence, we have shown that the only prime $p$ such that $p^2$ divides $2^p+3^p$ is $p=5$.

Comment: Thanks for embarrassing me with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** There exists such $n$ equal or smaller than $6$.

Answer (score -1):

Just plug in numnbers. n = 5 works.